# find limit of $f(z)=\frac{3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5}{z-i}$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find limit of $f(z)=\frac{3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5}{z-i}$ at $z=i$.

The problem seems easy but however I can't factor out $(z-i)$ from the numerator.

$$3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5=(z-i)(?)$$

How to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can also use L'hopital's rule (0/0) form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $z+i$ is also a factor.

Therefore you have $3z^4-2z^3+8z^2-2z+5=(z-i)(z+i)(\cdots)=(z^2+1)(\cdots)$.

It should be easier to compute now. In fact, $3z^4-2z^3+8z^2-2z+5=(z^2+1)(3z^2-2z+5)$.

Comment: Yes I got it @Qwertyuiop Thanks for your answer. I will accept your answer after 3min